# Gravity Forms Multiple Dates Filled by 1st Date

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms, datepicker

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to have multiple dates on a form be filled by the first date. I have 14 dates on the form. I want the user to pick the date on the first date and have the remaining dates autofill but cascading so it'll be two weeks of dates.

I have no idea if this is possible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This library will allow you to populate a series of fields in 2-week increments.

https://gravitywiz.com/populate-dates-gravity-form-fields/

The configuration would look something like this:

```php
new GW_Populate_Date( array(
    'form_id'         => 123,
    'source_field_id' => 1,
    'target_field_id' => 4,
    'modifier'        => '+2 weeks'
) );

new GW_Populate_Date( array(
    'form_id'         => 123,
    'source_field_id' => 1,
    'target_field_id' => 5,
    'modifier'        => '+4 weeks'
) );

new GW_Populate_Date( array(
    'form_id'         => 123,
    'source_field_id' => 1,
    'target_field_id' => 6,
    'modifier'        => '+6 weeks'
) );
```

The source field is the field that the user would select the date form. The target field would be populated with a new date based on the source date and the modifier.

In this example, we target a new target field with each instance and increment the modifier by 2 weeks. The source field and form ID stay the same.